# Revocar una consulta especifica en PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Bueno la pregunta es la siguiente,

Un Usuario podrá señalar en una consulta el nombre de los pacientes que NO tienen una ficha asociada, Pero otro usuario no podrá realizar ESTA consulta.

Se puede revocar dicho permiso? por que lo mas fácil seria hacer un revoke a un select general en la tabla, pero si se pudiera hacer seria genial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma puedes ser definir un rol, donde se definan usuarios con permisos de Select sobre la tabla  a realizar la consulta. Los usuarios que no se encuentren dentro de este rol no podrán realizar la consulta.

Asignas permisos select sobre la tabla pacientes para el rol `usuarios_pacientes` :

```
GRANT SELECT ON pacientes TO usuarios_pacientes;
```

Puedes agregar usuarios a tu rol:

```
GRANT usuarios_pacientes TO hawks;
```

Recuerda que puedes asignar permisos a diferentes objetos:
table, column, view, foreign table, sequence, database, foreign-data wrapper, foreign server, function, procedural language, schema, o tablespace.

En la **[documentación](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-grant.html)**, puedes obtener mas información.

Comment: Gracias, opte por esa forma mejor.

Saludos!